# sending he dynamic generated values to ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have this

```js
var cData={};
var arr=[];
datacolumns.split(",").forEach((element)=>{
    arr.push({data:element.trim()})
    cData[element] = `$(#${element.trim(0)}).val()`;
});
```

but when I call the cData in the ajax Data:cData, it is sending the form as

```
authorid    "$(#authorid).val()"
firstname   "$(#firstname).val()"
lastname    "$(#lastname).val()"
sorted  "$(#sorted).val()"
```

what is going on here, I have zero clue

Comment: providing a snippet would greatly increase chance of resolving your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using the backticks incorrectly. If `element` is a string, you should not need to use them.

```
var cData={};
var arr=[];
datacolumns.split(",").forEach((element)=>{
  var el = element.trim();
  arr.push({ data: el });
  cData[el] = $("#" + el).val();
});
```

So as you go through the loop, you should get a new selector each time:

```
$("#authorid").val();
$("#firstname").val();
$("#lastname").val();
$("#sorted").val();
```

As long as these elements exist with the proper ID and have `value` attributes, this should work to populate your Object.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have a little problem with your code. You need to change this:

```
cData[element] = `$(#${element.trim(0)}).val()`;
```

to this:

```
cData[element] = $(`#${element.trim(0)}`).val();
```

Note the placement of the backticks (`). You have wrapped the whole right-hand operand into the backticks which made it a string while what you really wanted to achieve was to wrap only the selector part.

Comment: i tried your code, but it is sending empty values even i passing some values to it

Comment: It seems like it's connected to your inputs being empty and not the code itself